# Listview virtualmode not able to add items dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listview

So I've been playing around with the `ListView` in virtualmode, but I can't seem to add items dynamically. I want to load items from a `List` and display them in my `ListView`. Here is the code I have so far.

```
private void listviewGames_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (listGames[1].Count < 1) return;

    for (int index = 0; index < listGames[1].Count; index++)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

        lvi.Text = listGames[1][index];

        e.Item = lvi;
    }
}
```

Sadly, this code doesn't seem to work, it only adds the last item in the `List`, why is this?
Thanks in advance,

Sapphire ~

Comment: did you set the VirtualListSize property?

Comment: @terrybozzio Yes I did, in the form_Load event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
private void listviewGames_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (listGames[1].Count < 1) return;


    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

    lvi.Text = listGames[1][e.ItemIndex];

    e.Item = lvi;

}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Learned something new today :). Thank you ^-^~ !